# Console throwing error with style property

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Everything is working as expected only that the console is throwing this error. Can anyone determine why?

Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

```
function openEditTable(tableid, DDid, ADid, Editid, UCid){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
    var DDid = document.getElementById(DDid);
    var ADid = document.getElementById(ADid);
    var Editid = document.getElementById(Editid);
    var UCid = document.getElementById(UCid);

    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        col = row.cells[8];
        col.style.display = '';
        DDid.style.display = 'none';
        ADid.style.display = 'none';
        Editid.style.display = 'none';
        UCid.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all the elements exist?

Comment: One or more selectors are misspelled or the referenced element(s) don’t exist.

Comment: I didn't specify, it's only throwing it for the 'col' variable. Like I said everything is working as expected despite the error..

Comment: I think it could be the way my table is laid out with colspan's towards the end of the table.

Comment: Please share your html table as well, i think the columns are less than 9 and cell[8] seems to be undefined , sample code for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vYYNeqM , where cells[0], cell[1], cells[2] works and fails with cells[8] as there is no 9th column

Comment: It was my table set up. had colspans on my last three rows thus not having and 9th column. I changed the id to support the tbody (which holds the 9 columns) and it is no longer throwing the error. Thank you for the input

Comment: Check value and assign if(row.cells[8]) and other option is to find index of column name and using the same to set style , so that it will always be defined.. posted sample working code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of finding position of column and using same index for styling the cell

Sample working code for reference

```js
function openEditTable(tableid, colName){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
      let index;
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

       for (var j = 0; j<row.cells.length; j++) {
          if(row.cells[j].textContent ===colName){
             index = j
          }
         if(row.cells && row.cells[index]){
              row.cells[index].style.color = 'red';      
         }

    } 
   } 
}

openEditTable('tableid', 'Lastname')
```

```css
table tr td{
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="tableid">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gOOaXvr